# Ubuntu 16.04 does not show the login screen on booting

Tags: boot, grub2, login-screen

My machine was  working completely fine till I restarted it, and now I cant reach the login screen. After turning ON the machine I can reach the GRUB where I select Ubuntu, after which I get a black screen, where I expect a login screen to appear. I did check some other posts but none seemed helpful
I haven't made any changes recently, I don't have a lot of experience with Ubuntu so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you greeted with a black screen or terminal prompt?

If only a black screen -> enter the grub menu and highlight the Ubuntu option.
Press the 'e' key and add the text `nomodeset` before `quiet splash`. The result should be `nomodeset quiet splash`, then press ctrl+x to load the OS. If this does fix your problem then at least you know it may be a video driver problem.

If you do get to a prompt (try 'ctrl+alt+F1' or 'ctrl+alt+F2', the GUI is usually on ctrl+alt+F7) you could try and start the login screen with `sudo service lightdm start`. If this does work you may have a different problem, maybe installing the display manager again will fix any errors. To install it type `sudo apt-get install lightdm`.

If starting the lightdm does not work you could try a more basic debugging option by typing `startx` at the prompt, perhaps this will help you shed some light on the problem.